# Attempting to parse dynamic JSON in iOS

Tags: ios, json, swift, codable, decodable

I have produced the following sample block of JSON. Any value that ends with a letter is dynamic.

```
{
    "groupName": {
        "groupA": {
            "fields": {
                "fieldA": "valueA",
                "fieldB": "valueB"
            },
            "letters": {
                "letterA: "A"
            }
        },
        "groupB": {
            "fields": {
                "fieldC": "valueC",
                "fieldD": "valueD"
            },
            "letters": {
                "letterB: "B"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My goal is to use `Decodable` so that I may read this data into `struct`s that I have defined.

Below is my current work contained in a playground file that I am using to try and resolve this:

```
import Foundation

let jsonString = "{\"groupName\":{\"groupA\":{\"fields\":{\"fieldA\":\"valueA\",\"fieldB\":\"valueB\"},\"letters\":{\"letterA:\"A\"}},\"groupB\":{\"fields\":{\"fieldC\":\"valueC\",\"fieldD\":\"valueD\"},\"letters\":{\"letterB:\"B\"}}}}"

struct CustomCodingKeys: CodingKey {
    var intValue: Int?
    var stringValue: String

    init?(intValue: Int) { self.intValue = intValue; self.stringValue = "\(intValue)" }
    init?(stringValue: String) { self.stringValue = stringValue }

    static let field = CustomCodingKeys.make(key: "field")

    static func make(key: String) -> CustomCodingKeys {
        return CustomCodingKeys(stringValue: key)!
    }
}

// Values
struct Field {
    let field: String
    let value: String
}

struct Letter: Decodable {
    let title: String
    let letter: String
}

// Value holders
struct FieldData: Decodable {
    var fields: [Field]

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        self.fields = [Field]()
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CustomCodingKeys.self)
        for key in container.allKeys {
            print("processing field: \(key.stringValue)")
            let dynamicKey = CustomCodingKeys.make(key: key.stringValue)
            let value = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: dynamicKey)
            let field = Field(field: key.stringValue,
                              value: value)
            fields.append(field)
        }
    }
}

struct LetterData: Decodable {
    var letters: [Letter]

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        self.letters = [Letter]()
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CustomCodingKeys.self)
        for key in container.allKeys {
            print("processing letter: \(key.stringValue)")
            let dynamicKey = CustomCodingKeys.make(key: key.stringValue)
            let value = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: dynamicKey)
            let letter = Letter(title: key.stringValue,
                                letter: value)
            letters.append(letter)
        }
    }
}

// Containers
struct Group: Decodable {
    var name: String!
    var groups: [GroupData]

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        self.groups = [GroupData]()
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CustomCodingKeys.self)
        for key in container.allKeys {
            print("processing section: \(key.stringValue)")
            let group = try container.decode(GroupData.self,
                                             forKey: key)
            groups.append(group)
        }
    }
}

struct GroupData: Decodable {
    var fieldData: FieldData
    var letterData: LetterData

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case fieldData = "fields"
        case letterData = "letters"
    }
}

struct GroupList: Decodable {
    struct GroupName: Decodable {
        var name: String!
        var groups: [Group]

        init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
            self.groups = [Group]()

            let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CustomCodingKeys.self)
            for key in container.allKeys {
                let name = key.stringValue
                self.name = name
                print("processing group: \(String(describing: self.name))")
                var group = try container.decode(Group.self,
                                                 forKey: key)
                group.name = name
                groups.append(group)
            }
        }
    }

    let groupName: GroupName
}

let decoder = JSONDecoder()
if let data = jsonString.data(using: .utf8),
    let groupList = try? decoder.decode(GroupList.self,
                                        from: data) {
    print("group list created")
}
```

In my `GroupData` struct, I can drop the variables and then implement `init(from decoder: Decoder) throws`, which when configured with the proper lookups (the FieldData & LetterData inits), can identify the correct pairs. However, it does not populate the proper value structs.

Comment: Honestly, I would advise you to move "dynamic" keys into data and use lists instead of objects. It will make your parsing a lot easier and you will get much more structure than a simple `[String:Any]` which is a casting nightmare. You are trying to do things different from "mainstream" which is generally a Good Thing (TM), but in this case you are producing yourself more trouble than it is worth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have small mistake in decoding `Group`. You tend to decode all keys for group inside `Group` and also you pass further the to decode `GroupData` which itself has "fields" and "letters". Use single value container inside `Group` and it should be fine.

Here is how your `Group` should look,

```
struct Group: Decodable {
    var name: String!
    var groups: GroupData

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
        groups = try container.decode(GroupData.self)
    }
}
```

Note, your json itself is incorrect, I have formatted it and it should rather be like this,

```
let jsonString = "{\"groupName\":{\"groupA\":{\"fields\":{\"fieldA\":\"valueA\",\"fieldB\":\"valueB\"},\"letters\":{\"letterA\":\"A\"}},\"groupB\":{\"fields\":{\"fieldC\":\"valueC\",\"fieldD\":\"valueD\"},\"letters\":{\"letterB\":\"B\"}}}}"
```

Comment: Thanks @sandeep. The JSON was just me making a mistake while making sample code, but the real JSON is valid & I should have caught that!